# QGIS Handling Heatmap Data Range

Tags: qgis, heat-map, visualisation

I have a grid of hexagons with data (ranging between 0 and 1) and, using the centroids of the hexagons as a base, I would like to visualise the data as a heatmap.

On the technical side, this works without issues. However, although I use the same color scale (Green to Red), the heatmap is heavily leaning in the red direction when leaving the "Maximum value" on *automatic*. This "red-shift" is amplified by increasing the heatmap-radius, which makes me assume that it's a result of a sinking "Maximum value" (due to the increasing smoothing-effect with increased radius).

To combat this problem, I can manually increase the maximum value until the heatmap data "looks good". However, this strikes me as not only an inferior method but also an error source.

Is there a better way to visualize my data consistenly as a heatmap?

*As a less important follow-up question: if I manually set the maximum values, I need to set values above 1 to obtain reasonable values (value needs to be higher with increasing heatmap-radius). Is this a result of how the kernel-density-function works or what causes this?*

**Hexagon data**

[image: Hexagon data]

**Data as a heatmap (with notable red-shift)**

[image: Data as a heatmap (automatic maximum)]

**Data as a heatmap (maximum value manually corrected)**

[image]

Comment: The heat map renderer also have a "Radius" setting, if you want your heat map to look more like your first map I think it should be set to a value close to your hexagon size.

Comment: Heatmaps are no exact way of visualizing data, so anyhow, regardless of what settings you use, you should be carefully reflect how your data are visualized. And - by the  way - in cartography, it is best practice to avoid red/green contrasts for colorblind issues, see e.g. https://www.esri.com/arcgis-blog/products/arcgis-living-atlas/mapping/red-green-what/ and https://www.gislounge.com/making-color-blind-friendly-maps/

Comment: @JR: The goal is to smoothen the data, without resulting in a red-shift. If I wanted the heatmap to look exactly like the hexagons, I would just use the hexagons instead.

Comment: @Babel: Thanks for the reminder about the color scale.

Comment: @ZHTank sure but I think that adjusting the radius will give better result than changing the maximum value

Comment: @JR: hmm, I don't know what to tell you; looks like we have different understanding of the use-case of heatmaps